# What happened to the Israel-UAE visa-free agreement?

Tags: visas, israel, uae

[In January 2021](https://www.timesofisrael.com/uae-delays-visa-waiver-agreement-with-israel-until-july-amid-pandemic/) it was announced that the Israel-UAE visa-free policy will become operational in July 2021:

> The United Arab Emirates on Monday informed the Foreign Ministry that it was pushing off the implementation of a visa waiver agreement with Israel until July 1 due to the coronavirus pandemic.

However Timatic is still saying that a visa is required for UAE nationals visiting Israel and Israeli nationals visiting the UAE. The only updates from July I can find [relate to UAE opening a consulate](https://www.timesofisrael.com/just-the-beginning-uae-opens-tel-aviv-embassy-as-sides-hail-ties/) in Tel Aviv. The UAE consulate [has a page on visas](https://www.mofaic.gov.ae/he-il/missions/tel-aviv/services/visas) that confirms a visa is required for Israeli citizens.

So... what happened to the agreement? Is it now cancelled permanently?

Comment: My best guess is that it's due to COVID fourth wave (Delta variant) hitting in full force for several months now. Israel became "red country" in many places. Back in January, people were sure that until July COVID in Israel will disappear due to the vaccine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The visa-free agreement is now in effect.

[A Timatic query using the Emirates site](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-uae-visa-requirements/?nationality=il&destination=ae) says:

```
Visa required.

Visa Exemptions:
Nationals of Israel for a maximum stay of 90 days. Information: The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.

Visa Issuance:
E-visas can be obtained before departure at https://smart.gdrfad.gov.ae/HomePage.aspx (for Dubai) or https://smartservices.ica.gov.ae/echannels/web/client/default.html#/login (for other emirates). Passengers must have a printed e-visa confirmation.
```

According to [this Hebrew site](https://passportnews.co.il/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%96%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA/) this is in effect since 10/10/2021 (European date format).

Comment: I suppose you don't really need to specify the date format for that particular date.